# Looking for java library for directories synchronization

Tags: java, file, directory

I'm looking for a java library (not tool) that will provide synchronizing local directory with directory on server (ftp). What I need is to put a set of files on server and then I want all clients to have (download when required) the same version of these files.

I noticed that VFS depends on time of file modification. What I need is a library that will use mechanism like hash/delta. Something like rsync, but lib not tool.

Comment: There was this discussion on it centered around [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) ...   http://stackoverflow.com/q/1246255/346387

Comment: Thanks, I already read this discussion. Unfortunatelly it did not gave me an answer. I need stable and still supported utils library (my company policy). Moreover I can't run rsync tool, because of 1. OS and 2. developed application licence terms.

Comment: I had exactly this problem for a project last year. I did a lot of investigations, but finally I didn't find any Java library for this. I gave up, and wrote a custom code.

Answer (score 1):

[Commons / VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs) is an abstraction over different file systems and protocols (including FTP) with a common API. It has an ant task called [`SyncTask`](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/vfs/tasks/SyncTask.html) that synchronizes two virtual file systems (one or more of which can be a real file system). [Ant task docs are here](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/anttasks.html#V-Sync). Perhaps you can either use that or look into [the underlying code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/vfs/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/vfs2/tasks/).

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for, but the underlying code looks promising. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Still, it's not what I need.But thanks for help.