# Synchronizing directories over FTP

Tags: java, ftp

I'm working on an app (Android) where instances of the application share data with each other via an FTP server. FTP has been used because the router I'm working with can be an FTP server using a plugged in USB flash drive.

One function the app is to perform is to sync its data with the other instances. At the moment the syncing is only additive. Any data on the server that isn't on the phone gets transferred to the phone. Any data on the phone that isn't on the server gets transferred to the server. The idea is that all the data created on all the phones can be mutually shared.

I've looked at some java rsync libraries. However, of the ones I have seen they are either unmaintained, are poorly documented, or both. Also, rsync isn't going to work given the hardware I'm operating with at the moment.

I have been using the Apache Commons Net FTPClient. I made a class that builds on top of it that offers methods to push and pull data from the server. However, if there exists a library (or approach) out there that has been tested thoroughly or offers more functionality, I would like to use it. Is there?

Comment: 'sync' is a complicated thing, and depending on what it means to you, it may be rellatively trivial.... but if you need to do any logic on the ftp server side then ftp is not the right tool. use something like rsync over ssh...  http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/rsync.1.php

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do is beyond the scope of the FTP protocol.  It is not impossible, but in order to do it you would need to parse the (implementation specific) output of the LIST command to extract timestamps and file sizes.  The [Apache FTPClient library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) can do this, though the degree to which it will work depends on what the target FTP server returns.

Note that the real 'rsync' command uses checksums to minimize transfers.  An FTP-based solution can't this.

Related:

- [Looking for java library for directories synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044116/looking-for-java-library-for-directories-synchronization)